# Repeating each element of a vector by a number of times provided by another counts vector

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy vector of counts such as this

`[2, 4, 3]`

and I am trying to create an array of its indexes

`[0, 1, 2]`

with each index repeated the number times specified by the corresponding count, ie, the final output should be

`[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`

It's easy but inefficient to do this using a for loop. Is there a fast vectorized solution?

Comment: Use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) (e.g. `np.repeat([0, 1, 2], [2, 4, 3])`). In plain Python, `[i for i, r in zip([0, 1, 2], [2, 4, 3]) for _ in range(r)]`.

Comment: Though it may not be possible for your use case, I think the best solution would be to try to not create that expanded list in the first place, and modify whatever code expects the list to accept the counts.